# Java array getting the length of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, size

I've tried to figure it out, but couldn't find any reference:

If I get one dimension array's size by: `MyArray.length()`,
 how can I get the dimensions of the 2D array, each dimension by itself?

Thank you

Comment: For which "array" ?

Answer (score 0):

If your 2D array is symmetric and square, you can use:

```
2Darray.length * 2Darray[0].length
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will return number of element in an 2D array:

Code:

```
static int length(int[][]  array, int NoColumnInArray){
int leng =0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < NoColumnInArray ; i++)
      leng+=array.length();
 return leng;
}
```